# Can't run docker without sudo on NixOS

Tags: docker, nix, nixos

I followed this: https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Docker, and in my configuration.nix i have

```
users.users.<myUsername> = { #my actual username
    isNormalUser = true;
    description = "<myUsername>";
    extraGroups = [ "networkmanager" "wheel" "kvm" "libvirtd" "docker"];
    packages = with pkgs; [];
  };
virtualisation.docker.enable = true;
```

and in /etc/group

```
docker:x:131:<myUsername>
```

I logged in and out but I still need to type sudo every time? I'm very new to nix and new-ish to linux and I have no idea what could be wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Permission to access Docker is controlled by the permissions on the Docker socket, `/var/run/docker.sock`. Check the group and permissions on that socket and see if they are correct.

Comment: @larsks srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Jun 26 00:30 /var/run/docker.sock

Comment: This is a dumb question because I am unfamiliar with nixos: Have you
confirmed you are in the `docker` group by running the `groups`
command after logging in? Otherwise that looks fine.

Comment: Oh when I run groups I don't see docker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logging in and back out was not enough. Restarting worked.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Same for me, logging out didn't work, but restart worked! I wonder why...

Comment: @ChrisGuida, some changes require reboot, so basically if you change something in kernel or system services it's better to reboot if anything goes wrong